# jQuery not submitting form after .load()

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a page that loads, and then when load is complete it uses Jquery to load content into a box.
That box contains a form. What I wanted it to do was to be able to submit the form via jQuery as well. However when I attempt it, the page just refreshes and I get the GET variables in the URL bar.

jQuery, does load and suppose to submit form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#passchangebox").load("boxes/settings_security_password.php?uID=" + uID, function() {
    $(".form_error").hide();
    $("#changepasswordloader").hide();
});
$("#passwordchange").submit(function(event) {  
    $('.form_error').hide();  
    var pass = $("input#pass").val();  
    if (pass === "") {  
        $("#pass_error").show();  
        $("input#pass").focus();  
        return false;
    }
    cpass = $("input#cpass").val();  
    if (cpass === "") {  
        $("#cpass_error").show();  
        $("input#cpass").focus(); 
        return false;
    }
    if(pass !== cpass){
        $("#match_error").show();  
        $("input#cpass").focus(); 
        return false;
    }
    email = $("input#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/settings_passwordchange.php",
        data: $('#passwordchange').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == 1){       
                $('input#pass').val("");
                $('input#cpass').val("");
                $('#payment_window_message_success').fadeIn(300);
                $('#payment_window_message_success').delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#payment_window_message_error_mes').html("An error occured, form was not submitted");
            $('#payment_window_message_error').fadeIn(300);
            $('#payment_window_message_error').delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
});
```

The PHP that is loaded into the page, and contains the form:

```
<?php
//get required config file and check login
if(!@include("../connect.php")){
    echo"<aside>
        <div class='error' id='errorconnecthide-this'>
            <img src='http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_error.png' class='messageimg' />
            <h4>Error - Current Page</h4>
            <p>There was an error making a connection to the database. Please try again later.</p>
        </div>
    </aside>";
} elseif(isset($_GET['uID'])){
    $uID = strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['uID']));
    if(!is_numeric($uID)){
        echo"<aside>
            <div class='error' id='errorconnecthide-this'>
                <img src='http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_error.png' class='messageimg' />
                <h4>Error - User</h4>
                <p>There was an error retrieving the user information. Please try again later.</p>
            </div>
        </aside>";
    } else {
        //GET THE USERS EMAIL
        $get_custInfo = 'singleuser';
        $userInfo_ID = $uID;
        if(!include("../classes/global_userinfo_details.php")){
            echo"<aside>
                <div class='error' id='errorconnecthide-this'>
                    <img src='http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_error.png' class='messageimg' />
                    <h4>Error - User</h4>
                    <p>There was an error retrieving the user information. Please try again later.</p>
                </div>
            </aside>";
        } else {
            $details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userInfo_qry);
            $email = stripslashes($details['userinfo_email']);
            echo"<form class=\"halfboxform\" id=\"passwordchange\">
                <fieldset>
                    <br />
                    <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"email\" value=\"$email\" />
                    <label for=\"pass\">New Password:</label>
                    <input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" id=\"pass\" size=\"45\" />
                    <p class=\"form_error clearb red input\" id=\"pass_error\">This field is required.</p>
                    <label for=\"cpass\" class=\"clearb\">Confirm:</label>
                    <input type=\"password\" name=\"cpass\" id=\"cpass\" size=\"45\" />
                    <p class=\"form_error clearb red input\" id=\"cpass_error\">This field is required.</p>
                    <p class=\"form_error clearb red input\" id=\"match_error\">Those passwords didnt match.</p>
                    <br class=\"clearl\" />
                    <br />
                    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update Login Details\" class=\"submit\" />
                </fieldset>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </form>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo"<aside>
        <div class='error' id='errordisplayhide-this'>
            <img src='http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_error.png' class='messageimg' />
            <h4>Error - Unknown</h4>
            <p>There was an error retrieving the necessary information. Please try again later.</p>
        </div>
    </aside>";
}
?>
```

Any help on this is really appreciated :D

Comment: Are you getting the requests on the server?

Comment: I noticed you seem to have your `header()` line after echoing quite a bit of code.  Shouldn't `header()` be the very first thing before anything else is output to the page?

Comment: No requests on the server. And yes to the header(); That's been changed, that was my bad in the pasting.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm getting off topic here, but is there a reason you are echoing all of the code as long strings rather than simply placing them outside of the PHP tags?  (For example, instead of `<?php if(somecondition)} { echo "some long code"; } ?>` you could do `<?php if(somecondition) { ?>  some long code <?php } ?>`)

Comment: I see a couple of things I would have done differently.  If you're not submitting the form the 'traditional' HTML way, then you don't really need the `FORM` tags.  You can keep the `INPUT` elements and just have the javascript/jquery detect the click of the submit button.  Also, instead of writing the 'dataString' as "key=value&key2=value2", I would have gone with "{ "key":value, "key2":value2 }".  I'm not positive if these would fix your issues, but you could try.

Comment: @vertigoelectric no real reason, I just find it easy and then I can usually see where an error occurs. Personal preference, unless it does actually speed the code up?
Also added the seralise option but still nothing. I did have that originally and then tried the datastring to see if it made any difference, but in both cases no.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was the move the submit function into the load success function as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#passchangebox").load("boxes/settings_security_password.php?uID=" + uID, function() {
        $(".form_error").hide();
        $("#changepasswordloader").hide();
        $("#passwordchange").submit(function(event) {
```

Was confident I had tried this before and it didnt work, whether it was a combination of the changes made from comment suggestions im not sure. Perhaps someone can enlighten as to why?!
Thanks to all that commented and helped with improvements.

Comment: I see.  You were trying to bind the event before the element existed.